# Where is the sys module located, or how to find it in Win 11 & Python

Tags: python, windows, sys, anaconda3

Does anyone know how to find where the `sys` module is installed in a Windows 11 install of anaconda3 & Python?  I've tried looking in the `Lib` folder already and although there is a file called `sys.py`, it seems awfully short for the number of methods exported by `sys`.  I also tried `sys.__file__` with no luck, does anybody know how I can find this thing?

Tried `sys.__file__` but it did not return a path, I also tried searching in the `Lib` folder of anaconda3 with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

It's not installed anywhere, it's baked into the interpreter itself. The module contains functionality that core Python relies on, and can't function without, so it's not a separately loaded module at all, even though you import it like one.

It's not even in the normal `Modules` directory of the CPython source tree (where C extension module source code normally lives; `Lib` is for modules implemented in Python), [it's in the `Python` directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/sysmodule.c) (where the core interpreter source code lives).

Comment: I was afraid of that, so there's no way to look at the implementation of the methods in the sys module?  It's probably in C or something isn't it?

Comment: @Tw3rkDaN3twerk: Yep. But you can look at their implementation just fine, I put the link to the source code in my answer. Handy tip if you're using `ipython` as your interactive interpreter (you should be, it's *much* better than the default): Any Python module implemented in Python can display the source code by `import`ing the module, then doing `modulename??`, and `ipython` will display the source code. The same works for a class/object/method implemented in Python if want to see the source code for it. But for anything implemented in C, it can only show you the docstring/prototype.